# What is the function of 得 in 我聽日仲有得面試添 in Cantonese?

Tags: grammar, usage, cantonese

I would like to ask about the function of 得 in this sentence:

> 我聽日仲有得面試添。

I understood the sentence as: "Tomorrow I still have an interview (additionally, on top of something else that might not have been mentioned)."

My question is why is there a "得"? I think the statement "我聽日仲有面試添。" without the "得" might have been perfectly fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

得 here is part of an auxiliary verb: 有得 /冇得 in Cantonese.

- 有得 = (Mandarin: 能/ 可以) = able to (qualified to)/ can
- 冇得 = (Mandarin: 不能/ 不可以) = unable to (not qualified to)/ cannot

> 我聽日仲**有**面試添 = I also **have** an interview tomorrow (notice: *面試 here is a noun for "an interview"*)

> 我聽日**有得**面試添 I **can** (qualified to) do an interview tomorrow (notice: *面試 here is a verb for "to do an interview"*)

> 我聽日**冇得**面試 = I **can't** (not qualified to) do an interview tomorrow

More examples of 有得 /冇得:

> 考試合格**有得**去旅行 -  pass the exam and you **can** go on the field trip

> 考試唔合格**冇得**去旅行 - fail the exam and you **can't** go on the field trip

> 六十五歲或以上**有得**攞養老金 - A person 65 years old or older **can** receive an old-age pension

> 六十五歲以下**冇得**攞養老金 - a person under 65 years old **can't** receive an old-age pension

Note:

In Mandarin, the auxiliary verb 得 means 要 = "have to; must" e.g. 我明天還**得**面試 (I still **have to** do an interview tomorrow).

Comment: extremely clear discussions, as always. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Intuitively, I would say the two sentences are somewhat different in meaning. With 得 you frame the interview positively, so you could alternatively translate the sentence as "Tomorrow I still get to have an interview" which implies that you are happy to do the interview. Whereas without 得 you frame the interview neutrally/negatively, i.e. it could imply that you are not looking forward to the interview.

Example:
如果你坐定定，可能有得食糖啊！("If you sit still, you might get to have candy/a sweet!")

With 添 at the end, as you rightly mentioned, suggests the interview is additional on top of something else, so the sentence with 得 might imply that 'the other thing' is good, whereas without 得  might imply that it is not. However I'm not sure how these bits of colloquial language might be formalised in terms of linguistics/grammar terminology.

Comment: adding 得 to 有 to make it "有得" doesn't necessarily frame the verb positively, for example, 有得震冇得瞓 (can only get scared, but can't get any sleep); 監都有得你坐 ( you can go to jail for that). You are using Mandarin grammar to interpret a Cantonese term. Please read my answer, The 有(have) in Mandarin has a different meaning in the Cantonese term 有得 (able + get = can)

Comment: @TangHo "有得震冇得瞓" - There's a bit of sarcasm here. You don't get to sleep but you "get to" tremble. Same with 有得坐監.